# GraohQL: how to create a query parameter constraint

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql, graphql-codegen

How do I validate a GraphQL query parameter. I want the bookings query not to receive negative values on page parameter.

I am using these modules for `typescript` types generation, is it possible to generate a constraint? (page > 0)

```json
{
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "2.6.2",
    "graphql-codegen/typescript": "2.4.5"
{
```

```html
type Booking { 
    id: ID!
    totalPrice: Float!
    user: User!
    event: Event!
    address: Address!
    createdAt: String!
}

type Query {
    bookings(page: Int!): [Booking!]!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither GraphQL scheme nor Typescript support this type of restriction. I suggest you instead control it server-side

Update:

There is, in fact, an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-constraint-directive) implementing it

Comment: https://github.com/confuser/graphql-constraint-directive/issues/11

Comment: not working on query arguments